# Check if two values within consecutive dates are identical

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate, tibble

Let's say I have a tibble like

```
df <- tribble(
  ~date,       ~place, ~wthr,
  #------------/-----/--------
  "2017-05-06","NY","sun",
  "2017-05-06","CA","cloud",
  "2017-05-07","NY","sun",
  "2017-05-07","CA","rain",
  "2017-05-08","NY","cloud",
  "2017-05-08","CA","rain",
  "2017-05-09","NY","cloud",
  "2017-05-09","CA",NA,
  "2017-05-10","NY","cloud",
  "2017-05-10","CA","rain"
)
```

I want to check if the weather in a specific region on a specific day was same as yesterday, and attach the boolean column to `df`, so that

```
tribble(
  ~date,       ~place, ~wthr, ~same,
  #------------/-----/------/------
  "2017-05-06","NY","sun",    NA,
  "2017-05-06","CA","cloud",  NA, 
  "2017-05-07","NY","sun",    TRUE,
  "2017-05-07","CA","rain",   FALSE,
  "2017-05-08","NY","cloud",  FALSE,
  "2017-05-08","CA","rain",   TRUE,
  "2017-05-09","NY","cloud",  TRUE,
  "2017-05-09","CA", NA,      NA,
  "2017-05-10","NY","cloud",  TRUE,
  "2017-05-10","CA","rain",   NA
)
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a logical column, you check `wthr` value if equal to row before using `lag` after grouping by `place`. I added `arrange` for date to make sure in chronological order.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(place) %>%
  mutate(same = wthr == lag(wthr, default = NA))
```

**Edit**: If you want to make sure dates are consecutive (1 day apart), you can include an `ifelse` to see if the difference is 1 between `date` and `lag(date)`. If is not 1 day apart, it can be coded as `NA`.

Note: Also, make sure your date is a `Date`:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

df %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(place) %>%
  mutate(same = ifelse(
    date - lag(date) == 1, 
    wthr == lag(wthr, default = NA),
    NA))
```

**Output**

```
   date       place wthr  same 
   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <lgl>
 1 2017-05-06 NY    sun   NA   
 2 2017-05-06 CA    cloud NA   
 3 2017-05-07 NY    sun   TRUE 
 4 2017-05-07 CA    rain  FALSE
 5 2017-05-08 NY    cloud FALSE
 6 2017-05-08 CA    rain  TRUE 
 7 2017-05-09 NY    cloud TRUE 
 8 2017-05-09 CA    NA    NA   
 9 2017-05-10 NY    cloud TRUE 
10 2017-05-10 CA    rain  NA
```

Comment: What if the entire 8th row is missing(i.e. the next row of `"2017-05-09", "NY", "cloud"` is `"2017-05-10", "NY", "cloud"`)? Is there a way to make the `same` value for the last row `NA` instead of `TRUE`?

Comment: @hmje Please see edited answer. You could check to make sure the rows are 1 day apart. If not, code as `NA`. Would that work for you?